# ModelAdmin DataObjects

Tags: silverstripe, modeladmin

I have this class:

```
class Product extends DataObject { 
    static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar', 
        'ProductType' => 'Varchar', 
        'Price' => 'Currency'
    ); 
}
```

The database table looks as follows:

```
 --------------------------------- 
| Name      | ProductType | Price |
|-----------+-------------+-------|
| Product 1 | Type1       | 100   |
| Product 2 | Type1       | 240   |
| Product 3 | Type2       | 10    |
| Product 4 | Type1       | 100   |
 ---------------------------------
```

I would like to have 2 model admins:

```
class MyFirstModel extends ModelAdmin {
    public static $managed_models = array(
        Product
    );
}

class MySecondModel extends ModelAdmin {
    public static $managed_models = array(
        Product
    );
}
```

What is the best way to come to this result:

- `MyFirstModel` should show me all entries where `ProductType` in table is `Type1`

And

- `MySecondModel` should show me all entries where `ProductType` in table is `Type2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getList()` should be the answer. DOC here http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/modeladmin#results-customization

So something like:

```
public function getList() {
    $list = parent::getList();
    if($this->modelClass == 'Product') {
        $list->exclude('ProductType', 'Type1');
    }
    return $list;
}
```

If you have more than 2 `ProductType` you can use an array to exclude multiple values like

```
$list->exclude('ProductType', array('Type2', 'Type3'));
```

Comment: Thank you! When adding a new Product: How can I ensure that i.e. adding a new Product in FirstModel save the value Type1 in row ProductType and when adding a Product within the SecondModel the value Type2 will be saved?

Comment: that will be a bit more complicated and not come straight out of the box. You might want to look at overloading `getEditForm()` on `ModelAdmin` and look at components on the GridField, maybe the `GridFieldAddNewButton`. Or maybe check the URL/Referrer in your DataObject's `getCMSFields()`. No promises here, you'll have to look around...